# sig-alternate.cls generates too much space at page bottom

Tags: spacing, letterspacing

I am using the ACM tex template `sig-alternate.cls` downloaded from [this page](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates), Option 2: LaTeX2e - Tighter Alternate style.

This page provides the minimum working environment, including files in the following figure.

[image]

I downloaded all the files and compile them with the CTeX suite (WinEdt 6, MikteX 2.9), the generated output PDF file has very large space at each page bottom, which differs from the original PDF on that page. My own generated PDF file can be found [here](http://s-router.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/~daihuichen/publications/sig-alternate.pdf), and the PDF provided by the ACM website is [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.pdf). You can compare them with each other.

I am wondering why the page bottom space is so large when I used `sig-alternate.cls`, and how can I reduce the space.

Comment: CTeX claims to be able to handle Chinese. So it is not surprised that your pdf is generated in A4 while ACM provides a sample in US-letter. Read [the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) for more layout.

Comment: By the way, CTeX is a suite containing several solutions such as LaTeX+CJK or XeLaTeX+XeCJK. Next time you have some problems on CTeX you should specify which part of CTeX you are using, compiler, [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), and so and so.

Comment: @Symbol1 I see, I forget to check the format. Though I am using CTeX, I am not writing in Chinese. I just like this software suite 'cause it integrates many useful tools.

Comment: The [last link](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.pdf) in the question is dead.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Because ACM updated their latex template, the link for the old template is no longer available.

Comment: That's a reason why we do not like external links. In this case it would has been better to upload two images to show the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I increased the `\topmargin` in the `sig-alternate.cls` file from 4.5pc to 6.5pc and it leveled out the margins.

Look for this line in the file.

```
\topmargin 6.5pc                % Nominal distance from top of page to top of box containing running head.
```

Comment: Maybe is would be better to look for a line with `\topmargin 4.5pc` and change it to, e.g., `\topmargin 6.5pc` … Nevertheless, if the problem is the page size (see the first comment to the questions), wouldn't it be better to change the page size instead of only to increase the top margin?

Comment: I set the page size from A4 to US-letter, and the question was resolved.